# Is it possible to invoke rest api inside TimerTrigger in Azure Functions

Tags: java, azure-functions, maven-3

Is it possible to invoke rest api inside TimerTrigger in Azure Functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is YES.

Answered myself after a long research. Azure instructions for local development helps to implement HttpTrigger but for other triggers, clarity is missing in documentation.

1. Login to Azure portal.
2. Create Azure Functions
3. Click Create New Function on the dashboard
4. Rest, you will be driven by the instructions.
5. We can invoke API from TimerTrigger function and it works with minimal effort.